# How to change status code of headers of response in serverless framwork?

Tags: http-headers, aws-lambda, serverless

I want to response personal defined statuscode and some headers.
But I find even I change the status code to 201 the status code is still 200. and my defined header is not in headers.

my handler like:

```
function createResponse(status, header, body) {
return {
headers: Object.assign(header, {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
}),
statusCode: status,
body: JSON.stringify(body)
}
}
export const hello = async (event, context, cb) => { 
const rep = {
  message: 'v1.0',
  event: event
};
cb(null, createResponse(201, {}, rep));
return;
};
```

I use serverless.yml my configuration is:

```
functions:
  first:
    handler: handlers/first.hello
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: first
          integration: lambda
```

How to check to correct code can change status code and response header?
I also find my headers still in response body, How to add my header part in Response headers?

If you think my intergration part have problem, can you give me correct configuration example?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a nested object inside headers.

Reference documentation,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

Here is the correct sample code to send the correct response,

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var res ={
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "*/*"
        }
    };
    res.body = "Hello, World !";
    callback(null, res);
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you are wrong. I already read this documentation and I did the same code. but found json feedback {"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Content-Type":"*/*"},"body":"Hello, World !"}. which is obviously the statusCode is not in response head part. it just json response body.

Comment: Your integration is not correct. You need to change your integration to ANY and with lambda proxy in API Gateway. You have direct integration to API Gateway, that is causing the problem.

Comment: Can you say it more clearly or give me correct exmple of integration to API Gateway, if I use serverless.yml configure it.